# Django models: Aggregate Sum over multiple foreign key field values

Tags: django, database, sum, aggregate, annotate

I have the following Django database Model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
     author = models.ForeignKey(User);
     target = models.ForeignKey(User);
     points = models.IntegerField(default=0);
```

Users can give another user points. The goal is to calculate the
Sum of points for each Tuple of Users. The obvious way is to use iteration but this would result in many unnecessary queries. While this is a rather simple SQL query I cant get it to work with djangos API. I played around with annonate, aggregate and Q filters but could not achieve the desired result.

Preferably the result would be something like:

```
[{'user_one_pk': 1, 'user_two_pk': 2, 'sum__points': 6},
 {'user_one_pk': 1, 'user_two_pk': 3, 'sum__points': -3},
 {'user_one_pk': 2, 'user_two_pk': 3, 'sum__points': 9}]
```

EDIT: edited result for clarification of unique tuples.

Comment: the best way is to do it in the database. write a simple function that does it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In django, you can try:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Entry.objects.all().values('author','target').annotate('sum__points'=Sum('points'))
```

Comment: I tried this. While the only problem was that this will not generate unique touples of user pks this is still usefull. All that is necesscary would be to sum up the equivalent touples. I only thought there may be a better way. eg: [{'target': 4, 'sum_pts': 1, 'author': 1}, {'target': 5, 'sum_pts': 4, 'author': 1}, {'target': 1, 'sum_pts': -3, 'author': 4}, {'target': 1, 'sum_pts': 1, 'author': 5}]

Comment: @Jones What do you mean by not generate unique tuples of user pks?

Comment: there will be the {1,2} and {2,1} touples

Comment: @Jones Yes even normal db queries will not do this, because though they reference the same model, they are 2 different fields. So, I think iteration is the only option if you want exactly what you ask for

Comment: Okay. i suppose thats not all that bad. If there will be no better solution within a few hours i will mark this question as solved by your answer. thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: @Jones No problem :) I can even help you with an iterative solution if that is what you want